# have problem running android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

here's the log:

……/android-sdk-mac_86/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu: Interrupted system call
 qemu: could not load kernel '……/android-sdk-mac_86/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu

Please help me solve this problem

//solved with reinstall the entire develop environment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your android run as cofiguration

Comment: But I even can't start the emulator using the AVD Manager, I tried to create a new AVD but it still doesn't work

Comment: i think there is error in your settings of run configuration somewhere, just check it out. don't create new but just check settings of emulator run cofiguration